# Daphne High CPU Usage with Channel 2 and Redis Layer

Tags: django, websocket, redis, django-channels, daphne

I am a Django developer, i have recently build a messaging app using Channels 2 and Redis. For each conversation i am creating a group and adding all the participant to the group every time when one reconnect.

I am also using workers for channels with Daphne on production

The problem is that after 10 groups for a user , the messaging get super slow with daphne using nearly 100 % CPU usage, causing all site slow.

I have attached the screehshots for the CPU usage.

[image: Data output screenshot]

I would be really thankful to you could advice to reduce CPU usage

Regards,
Saadullah Naeem

Comment: Please add the extra information into the question as an edit rather than posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, some error in tasks.py(celery) makes daphne cpu 100% usage.

The error log can be checked in asgi log file.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. I see a best performance with Uvicorn and Gunicorn.

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 mysite.asgi:application -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --workers 4
```

In this case I expecify 4 worker and It's use 4 core of server, and distributes the use of CPU.

[image]